# How to filter a photo to pencil and paper sketch with stains?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have tried a variety of different manipulations to achieve a old-style architectural render. Here is what I've tried, perhaps the workflow and quality can be improved.

1. Desaturated image
2. Adjusted levels and contrast for clear designation of lines
3. Filtered using artistic pencil sketch
4. Added sepia tone

my result was less than stellar.

Here is a photo that I would like to change into an old-style rendering.
[image: photo kitcen]

here is the result that I'm looking for.
[image: kitchen redering]

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 2):

The second image is a marker rendering, **not** a filtered photograph.

You will never get the same results with any automated or filter process. It takes manual illustration skills. The subtle variations in colors, lines, and perspective are all done by hand.

Sometimes the computer is simply not a substitute for traditional illustration skills. In order to pull this off digitally, you need to actually draw and paint it rather than trying to use any filters.

Set the photo as a layer at the bottom of a layer stack and use it as a template/guide and paint on layers above it.

[image: draw it]

Although, doing this by hand with pen paper and markers, will be much, much faster than trying to accomplish it digitally.

Comment: I totally agree, it is just that I lack appropriate and dexterity to do a nice simple trace/illustration.  I can hack around for 5 min and this is the closer i can get. See above.

Comment: for the above image, did you just trace it with different lines?

Comment: The above was just done with Photoshop's lien too quickly. It's honestly nowhere near what I'd consider adequate. The perspective lines don't all align as they should. This is why by hand will be much faster.